# IF formula containing another formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use the following formula

```
=LEFT(J16,SEARCH(",", J16) - 1) ---<where j16 contains the data>
```

To turn

```
'Application,Cost,Timeliness'
```

into

```
'Application'
```

My issue is if the the cell contains no commas "," then the formula doesn't work. How do I get it to check for commas first and if it contains them, apply the formula, if it doesn't, leave as is?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your formula within an `IFERROR` formula that returns J16 if an error exists.

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(J16,SEARCH(",", J16) - 1),J16)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

=IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(",",G16))),LEFT(G16,SEARCH(",", G16) - 1),"No Commas")

NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(",",G16)))  -->evaluates to either true or false

LEFT(G16,SEARCH(",", G16) - 1)   -->returned if true

"No Commas"   --returned if false

Comment: Thanks Marka, your formula worked perfectly as well, however i marked Mark Fitzgerald's answer correct as I needed it to return the original if there was no commas. Thanks!